# Should I work as consultant when I doubt the working methods they use

Tags: consulting

I'm offered to work as a consultant in a small software company. My role will be software developer and building up the it/software dev knowledge in the company.
Today they have some huge issues with how they are developing software. Some of them:

- There is no support for version control in the software being used for developing and the code is only stored in binary files.
- All data in the scripting part is basically handled as text strings, which creates a lot of problems (numbers,dates etc) and no support for object oriented programming.
- The product does not follow todays standard. Everything is put in to a client application, even tasks that should have been done on server side.

I've tried to talk a little with founder and developer in the company, but he is very happy with how they are doing it now and cannot se why they should change (even they specify my role as increasing the It/software dev knowledge). The economy of the company looks good and they reached out to many customers.

But its bugs, many of them, which should never occurr, but because of the way its beeing developed its kind of obvious this would have happened.

On one side, I think it might be a good thing to do if I actually can change the way they work, but on the other side, if they still continue the way they work and expect me to do the same, I really dont want my name on it.

As very much of the software was developed in the start by the founder, its kind of his baby and I'm not sure if its really touchable.

Any advice what to do in this kind of situation? should I tell them under these condition I don't think I will be able to do a good job for them and say no? should I just make a very specified contract of my roles and start up and check how it is?

Comment: How you done jobs like this before?

Comment: Not exactly this kind of role, but something similair i startups and as a employee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any advice what to do in this kind of situation?

You'll face this again in your life as an independent consultant/contractor. What the company does and how it does it isn't for you to decide. You can and should give them good advice and council, which you've done. The decision you have to make is whether or not you can work with them knowing that you disagree with their standards and methods. Can you deliver good work knowing what you know? Can you get past the fact that they're not doing things to your standards and methods? If so, then go forward with them. If not, then sever the relationship.

> should I tell them under these condition i don't think i will be able
> to do good job for them and say no?

If you decide not to move forward with this client you don't need to give them any reason for not doing so. You simply need to sever the relationship. If they ask, or if you're so inclined, you can tell them the specific reasons why. They may take it well and they may not.

> should I just make a very specified contract of my roles and start up
> and check how it is?

Regardless of what you decide with this client, your contract (and you should always have a contract) should be very specific regarding deliverables, payment, severability, etc.